# Plot max and min degree in python (networkx)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I'm stuck at the part where I need to iterate through the degree list because it doesn't let me?

I should plot 5 min degree nodes and 5 min ones based on the network i have. Any tips are welcome!

---

My code (from the comments):

```py
def max_node(iterable, k=10):
    max_degree = heapq.nlargest(k, enumerate(iterable), key=lambda x:x[1]) 
    return(max_degree)
```

Comment: Could you include your code together with the full error traceback? Take a look here [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), how to prepare your code. Then we are able to help you with your specific problem

Comment: In the meantime i fixed the problem but i dont get the results i want. Ive been trying multiple ways but the last one i tried is like this.  def max_node(iterable, k=10):
    max_degree= heapq.nlargest(k, enumerate(iterable), key=lambda x:x[1])
    return(max_degree)                                                                                                                    but i dont get the max values ordered i just get some random ones from the list..                 edit: sorry im lost with the formatting

Comment: You can simply edit your question and include their your code. The formatting of your code should within the question should be easier - and more readable for everyone ;)